# Android AIDL - need a sample client and server (two different apps)

Tags: android, client, noclassdeffounderror, aidl

I have two different apps - one a client and another a remote server and I am trying to use AIDL. I was able to compile the client by importing the server class, however bindService on client is returning false (even if I use getContenx().bindService(). Now if I try to use com.xyz.myRemoteServiceClassName.class.getName(), that is the name of the remote service in the client's onCreate method, the client throws a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception). Also my client currently does not have the AIDL file, but it compiles just fine with all the imports.

If I add the AIDL file in the server "as is" into the client, the client doesn't compile complaining about a parcelable object in the AIDL file. If i add the object too even then it complains..I have included the server project in the Java build path of the client.

Does anyone have a sample client and server (two different apps) code working. If so can you please point to (preferably an Eclipse project) that one can use to see client-server apps working?

Thanking in anticipation,

Ravi

--
Removed the source code.

Answer (score 0):

In the SDK, there are Samples.  One of which is **Remote Service Controller and Remove Service Binding**.  The files you need can be found in your SDK directory **[sdk]/samples/android-[version]/...**

The source for the remote service (also in the SDK) can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteService.html).

Comment: Hey thanks, I have seen that source code. What I am looking for is a simple *working* implementation of a IPC using AIDL, where there are two different apps one a client and another a server. My code is quite simple without any callbacks etc. I need a working sample, if anyone can please provide that would be really helpful.  

Ravi

Comment: That does work.  You're looking for another implementation other than what is included in the Sample.  Also, if you can include your code where you are having an issue, may be able to help with that.

Comment: I have added the code, can you please take a look, thank you.

Comment: Got it..Few steps for future prospects who will hit this bug:

1. Need to create a "server package" in the client app and copy AIDL files there, it will generate corr. Java files